# Horizontal chart bars (Silverlight Toolkit)

Tags: .net, xaml, charts, silverlight-toolkit, bar-chart

Is it possible to show bars horizontally?

```
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <StackPanel>
            <toolkit:Chart Height="400" Width="600" Title="Mered data" >              
                    <toolkit:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding AverageImpressionLengths}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding SeqName}"
                                          DependentValueBinding="{Binding Time}"  
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="304" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="266"/>

            </toolkit:Chart>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you should just replace `ColumnSeries` by `BarSeries`:

```
<toolkit:Chart Height="400" Width="600" Title="Mered data" >              
    <toolkit:BarSeries ItemsSource="{Binding AverageImpressionLengths}" 
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding SeqName}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Time}"  />
</toolkit:Chart>
```